style is not being targeted in scss stylesheet
I am currently trying to target a specific Column to set a certain style.
But I can't set the style how I want because its not changing a single thing.
I am giving it a className and setting it in the scss.
What am I doing wrong and how can I style something in the scss file if I need it styled a certain way.
.sunset {
    top: 50%;
}

const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Row className="position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <Col className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <h1 className='hero-title '>cloud</h1>
                    <CardImg className="sunset position-absolute" src={sunset} alt="sunset"/>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    )
}

The only bootstrap style that it provides is putting it @ 50 so I put it at top-50.
but I want the image at a certain point in the Row, right at the bottom of the title.

A minimal working code will be helpful for understanding.

what do you mean about minimal working code ? What code would you like to see ?

The code you have provided does not result in any output.

why does the code need to provide an output. I just want to know the correct way of styling a reactstrap component with sass. As you can see I have a className of sunset and in the reactstrap component it is displaying the name of the style but the style is not controlling the reactstrap component. Why do you need a visual ?
